# Show master view at startup and detail view on "slide over"

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller, in horizontal compact mode I would like it to show the master view controller upon startup. By default the split view controller will load the detail view at startup. This can be easily changed with this snippet:

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

This works fine for me, but when "sliding over" a new view and going from a regular horizontal width to a compact one, the master view is shown instead of the detail view. I would like the detail view to remain being shown as the user has already selected it. Example:

[image: Example GIF]

When I then return `false` in the above snippet I get the desired behaviour with slide over, but obviously now the app will start with the detail instead of the master. Example with `collapseSecondary` as `false`:

[image: Example GIF]

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? Start by presenting the master view controller, and showing the detail view controller when going from a regular horizontal width to a compact one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if `splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` is called on interface change.

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    BOOL runningInSplitView //do logic check here based on windows bounds
    if(!runningInSplitView)
     return true;
    return false;
}
```

else, you would have to properly handle using `optional func primaryViewController(forCollapsing splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController?` and its counterpart

Comment: The first one. As I already has the logic to know if a cell has been selected or not, I simply checked with my detail (secondaryViewController) and if a cell hadn’t been selected yet it would return false.